# Showing ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\n'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Here I am making a project which encripts the image and when I am running the code it is showing the ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\n'

my code:

```
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
def encript():
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("200x160")
    def encript_image():
        file1 = filedialog.askopenfile(mode='r', filetype=[('jpg file', '*.jpg')])
        if file1 is not None:
            # print(file1)
            file_name = file1.name
            # print(file_name)
            key = entry1.get(1.0, END)
            print(file_name, key)
            fi = open(file_name, 'rb')
            image = fi.read()
            fi.close()
            image = bytearray(image)
            for index, value in enumerate(image):
                image[index] = value^int(key)
            fi1 = open(file_name, 'wb')
            fi1.write(image)
            fi1.close()


    b1 = Button(root, text="encript", command=encript_image)
    b1.place(x=70, y=20)
    entry1 = Text(root, height=1, width=10)

    entry1.place(x=50, y=50)

    root.mainloop()
encript()
```

on running this code I got error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\n'
```

I don't know what I have to do in this

Comment: try printing `key`.

Comment: Sorry but printing key is showing error and we can't print only key because on using xor operator we have to use int and key is string not int

Comment: Sorry but printing key is showing error and we can't print only key because on using xor operator we have to use int and key is string not int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the error states that ‘\n’ is not a valid literal, because ‘\n’ is not an integer. Judging by the code provided, I see that you are trying to encrypt an image using XOR encryption (the ^ symbol), using a specified key. For this, you are trying to get the integer version of an ASCII char, however you are using int(), which converts integers in string literals into usable integers.

```py
x = int(“12”)
print(x) # Prints the integer 12
```

To get the integer version of an ASCII char, use ord()

```py
x = ord(‘a’)
print(x) # Prints the integer 97
```

Comment: It is really helpful to me